# Extract private key and certificate from kpcs7 (.p7b) file

Tags: security, openssl

I have a .p7b file. How do I extract the key and certificate? I tried openssl, but I am not able to get the exact command/options.

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

PKCS#7 file doesn't include private keys. As for certificate(s) you have not specified what platform you are using and how your question is related to programming.

Comment: Talking about archived key recovery there is an encrypted key in an PKCs#7: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc226732.aspx

Comment: @Daniel Fisher do you have a reference to the standard which specifies how to store private keys in pkcs7?

Comment: Nothing but the overview in MS TechNet https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730721.aspx

Comment: @Daniel Fisher as I understand it,  they use PKCS7 encryption where the private key is stored as a binary data being encrypted. This is different from how keys are stored in pkcs12 or how certificates themselves are stored in pkcs7.