# Get my private key

Tags: private-key, pfx, crt

I've just recieved a certificate from Commodo. The ZIP file contains a xxx.crt and xxx.pb7b

I need to convert the xxx.pb7b file in to a xxx.pfx so that I can import it in IIS. I'm using OpenSSL for the conversion, but I need a private.KEY file.

Is there away to get\extract this file??

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365125/extract-private-key-and-certificate-from-kpcs7-p7b-file

Comment: Already figure it out. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export the current certificate (PFX) that is about to expire. This file contains your certificate and public key. Then use OpenSSL to extract the private key from the PFX file.

**openssl pkcs12 -in  myfile.pfx -nocerts -out private_key.pem -nodes**